# should I configure my EC2 using user_data or Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, terraform

When launching EC2 using Terraform (or cloud formation), we can configure EC2 by putting some scripts in user_data/remote-exec. Alternatively, we can configure EC2 using Ansible/Chef, etc. What are the difference of configuring EC2 in user_data/remote-exec and do that with Ansible/Chef? when to use the former, when to use the latter (I know Ansible/Chef is idempotent)?

In my case, the EC2 is originally manually launched, then manually configured using a lot of linux commands. and the commands are not configured by me. Now I am the person to automate the whole structure using terraform, and configure EC2s. Using user_data/remote-exec to configure EC2 is straightforward. I just need to put all the existing linux commands they have in some scripts with a little change. And if the configuration result using my script is not successful, at least I can quickly figure out whether I miss some commands by comparing my script and the original linux commands. But if I use ansible/chef, I have to rewrite all the steps using different language. And if the configuration is not what expected, it is hard for me to figure out which steps are not correct, because the syntax of ansible/chef and linux commands are totally different.

My question is, in my case, should I use ansible/chef or user_data/remote-exec for configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Data is good for initial configuration of the system. If you need longer term maintenance a configuration management software like Ansible/Chef/Salt/Puppet is a great option.

[Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html) can be used for immutable infrastructure, i.e. doesn't change after creation. You can run all the scripts and installs on the system for it to be ready to just boot, this is also faster because you don't have to wait for user data to run.

A few questions you have to ask as well, how often are you going to patch these? Are you going to just update existing or replace with new. Ansible is great for configuration since it's just yaml files an

[Blue/Green deployments](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Blue_Green_Deployments.pdf) generally replace servers with all new ones and gradually move traffic over to the new servers.

[Some more things to consider with your Infrastructure as code](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/infrastructure-as-code.pdf)

Comment: hi, strongjz. I think I need to use chef/ansible, etc because the configuration need updating later on. Thx.

Comment: one concern of using Ansible/chef is that I am a devOps who is responsible of infrastructure as code. I did not design manual configuration commands. but it seems I have to be familiar with the commands in order to rewrite them to ansible code. is it always true?

Comment: I would try to understand what is the flow and implement that accordingly, If that is not possible you can always use the respective command modules http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_module.html http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/win_command_module.html